# Sidebar content goes under fixed header when reducing window height vertically

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, css-position, sidebar

**When I try to add a scroll bar to my sidebar when the window height is reduced vertically, the content goes under my fixed header.**

**Like this:**

[image]

**I tried adding a margin the size of my header but the scroll bar won't reach the bottom part of my sidebar.**

**Like this:**

[image]

**This is the code for my sidebar:**

**HTML:**

```
<aside class="sidebar" id="news">
    <article>
        <p>Cute cat becomes friend with mouse<br><a href="#">Read More</a></p>
        <p>Cat and dog pose for cute family photo<br><a href="#">Read More</a></p>
        <p>Woman says cat changed her life<br><a href="#">Read More</a></p>
        <p>There's a new fluffy hero in New York<br><a href="#">Read More</a></p>
        <p>The history of the great Egyption cats<br><a href="#">Read More</a></p>
        <p>Town elects cat as new mayor<br><a href="#">Read More</a></p>
        <p>Cat saves injured man<br><a href="#">Read More</a></p>
        <p>More stories at our <a href="#">News Center</a></p>
        <footer>&copy; Goodie Club 2021</footer>
    </article>
</aside>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* Sidebar for Tablet Landscape Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    body {
        grid-template-columns: 200px 4fr;
        grid-template-rows: 75px 1550px;
        grid-template-areas: 
        "header header" 
        "sidebar main";
    }

    .sidebar {
        display: block;
        grid-area: sidebar;
        background-color: #fbeec1;
    }

    .sidebar article {
        width: 200px;
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        position: fixed;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin-top: 75px;
    }

    .sidebar article p {
        margin: 0.9em 0.8em;
        font-family: 'Merienda', cursive;
        font-size: 0.98rem;
        line-height: 1.25em;
    }

    .showfooter {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

**The whole project with its codes is on my [GitHub](https://github.com/n-ii-ma/Goodie-Club) page and the page itself is [here](https://n-ii-ma.github.io/Goodie-Club/).**

***UPDATE:***

**After following Philo's solution, the problem is fixed but something else is happening. The content of the sidebar go under a bottom of sidebar as if there's a margin blocking them. This only happens in "Tablet Landscape".**

**Like this:**
[image]

Comment: I see the problem ? I will answer

Comment: If you want to respond to an answer, comment on it. Don't edit the question with it.

Answer (score 2):

**Hi**,

The problem specified in height of `.sidebar article`

***Old Answer***

Add `height: calc(100vh - "margin-top-value")` in `.sidebar .article`

like this:

`height: calc(100vh - 75px)`

***Update***

Just Delete the `height` property from `.sidebar article` or use `height: auto`

To let the browser detect the best height

See

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution! There's now another problem appearing and it's one part at the bottom of the sidebar that the content goes under. As if there's a margin. I'll update the post with the screenshot of the problem now.

Comment: Post is updated with screenshot of the new issue.

Comment: I got confused. Excuse!